# calling startActivityForResult from child activity in tabhost

Tags: android, android-intent, android-tabhost

I am using TabHost, extending Activity and using LocalActivityManager.

I am firing an intent from one of the child activities using startActivityForResult, but cannot get the result back to that child activity.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: what do you mean by cannot get the result - your onActivityResult is never called or what ?

Comment: Some code would help get you a better answer...did you add the onActivityResult result method?

Comment: Yes, I use onActivityResult(...) to capture the result.

Answer (score 1):

check if you are finishing the child activity? Also check if you are setting setresult properly.

Answer (score 1):

did you add this method to handle the result?

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
....
}
```